# Aligned inside table won't work with paragraphs?

Tags: tables

So I've been working with tables, and I wanted to make it so that each cell has 4 rows, while one column has aligned to align equations. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|c|}
\hline
Acid & Ionization in Water \\
\hline
Hydrochloric acid\\
Nitric acid\\
Nitrous acid\\
Ethanoic acid
&
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \text{HCI(aq)} & \rightarrow \text{H}^+\text{(aq)}+\text{CI}^-\text{(aq)}\\
    \text{HNO}_3\text{(aq)} & \rightarrow \text{H}^+\text{(aq)}+\text{NO}^-_3\text{(aq)} \\
    \text{HNO}_2\text{(aq)} & \rightleftharpoons \text{H}^+\text{(aq)}+\text{NO}^-_2\text{(aq)} \\
    \text{CH}_3\text{COOH(aq)} & \rightleftharpoons \text{H}^+\text{(aq)}+\text{CH}_3\text{COO}^-\text{(aq)}
\end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But instead of what I want, it became this:

[image: table]

Seems like the aligned is positioned at the last row of the paragraph. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm no chemist, but shouldn't one use `Cl`("C ell") instead of `CI` ("C eye") to denote the element chlorine?

Comment: the entries are in the left are not "a paragraph" you separated them with `\\ ` which means that they are in separate rows of the table (short rows with no second cell, which is why they have no vertical line on the right) then your aligned[t] in the second column aligns with the text in the first cell in that table row, which is "Ethanoic acid".

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Look as your original table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|r@{}c@{}l|}
    \hline
    Acid & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Ionization in Water} \\
    \hline
    Hydrochloric acid &
        \ch{HCI(aq)} & \ch{->} & \ch{H^+(aq) + CI^-(aq)}\\
    Nitric acid &
        \ch{HNO3(aq)} & \ch{->} & \ch{H^+(aq) + NO^-_3(aq)} \\
    Nitrous acid &
        \ch{HNO2(aq)} & \ch{<=>} &\ch{H^+(aq) + NO^-_2(aq)} \\
    Ethanoic acid & \ch{CH_3COOH(aq)} & \ch{<=>} & \ch{H^+(aq) + CH_3COO^-(aq)}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

However, I also suggest to you to use \texttt{booktabs} and get rid of
vertical rules, as in Table \ref{tab:book}.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{table}
\caption{Look with \texttt{booktabs}\label{tab:book}}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}r@{}c@{}l}
    \toprule
    Acid & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Ionization in Water} \\
    \midrule
    Hydrochloric acid &
        \ch{HCI(aq)} & \ch{->} & \ch{H^+(aq) + CI^-(aq)}\\
    Nitric acid &
        \ch{HNO3(aq)} & \ch{->} & \ch{H^+(aq) + NO^-_3(aq)} \\
    Nitrous acid &
        \ch{HNO2(aq)} & \ch{<=>} &\ch{H^+(aq) + NO^-_2(aq)} \\
    Ethanoic acid & \ch{CH_3COOH(aq)} & \ch{<=>} & \ch{H^+(aq) + CH_3COO^-(aq)}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also suggest to you to use `chemformula` package, I'm not a chemist but, as you can see, it simplifies a lot the formulas. And `booktabs` package for a better look of your table.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution which dispenses with the `aligned` environment and, instead, uses the machinery of the [mhchem](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/) package to typeset chemical formulas. (The syntax requirements of the `mhchem` and `chemformulas` packages are quite similar.)

I would also like to suggest that you give the table an "open" look by getting rid of all vertical lines and by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. I would also use `Cl` rather than `CI` to denote chlorine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mhchem,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25} % 1.5 seems excessive
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l r@{}c@{}l @{}}
\toprule
Acid & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Ionization in Water} \\
\midrule
Hydrochloric acid &
   \ce{HCl(aq)}     & \ce{->}  & \ce{H+(aq) + Cl-(aq)}  \\
Nitric acid &
   \ce{HNO3(aq)}    & \ce{->}  & \ce{H+(aq) + NO3-(aq)} \\
Nitrous acid &
   \ce{HNO2(aq)}    & \ce{<=>} & \ce{H+(aq) + NO2-(aq)} \\
Ethanoic acid &
   \ce{CH3COOH(aq)} & \ce{<=>} & \ce{H+(aq) + CH3COO-(aq)} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was editing my answer to add `booktabs` while you added yours :)!

Comment: No, you suggested another chemical package and also corrected the `Cl`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aligned` and a simple syntax for chemical reactions with `chemformula`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut, makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|c|}
    \hline
    Acid & Ionization in Water \\
    \hline
    \makecell[lt]{Hydrochloric acid \\
      Nitric acid \\
      Nitrous acid \\
      Ethanoic acid\bigstrut[b]}
         &
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \ch{HCI (aq) & -> H+ (aq) + CI- (aq) \\
        HNO (aq) & -> H+ (aq) + NO3- (aq) \\
        HNO2 (aq) & <=> H+ (aq) + NO2- (aq) \\
        CH3COOH (aq) & <=>H+ (aq) + CH3COO- (aq)}
      \end{aligned}$ \\%
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]